# AWS ELB(classic load balancer) response is too slow and sometimes response is not coming it is showing timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, security-groups, amazon-eks, eks

I have EKS cluster setup in private subnet in which i'm having my microservices and for each microservice i have classic load balancer to access API. But response is having high latency and sometimes it just timed out.

I have service A which talks to service B and service C but as response is not coming on time from B & C service it throws error.
The same case works fine in other environments(even the same code i'm having for microservices in other env.)

I have compared security groups for nodes and ELB with other environments as well but i can't see any change in that not sure why this is happening.
What can be the reason for this? Is there any way to check why ELB response is this slow?

Comment: I'd first recreate the ELB just in case there's a weird issue with the hardware, which is rare but does happen. You should probably switch to the more modern ALB unless there's a good reason to stick with ELB.

Comment: @Tim i have tried deleting and creating new ELB still the issue remains same. And as for ELB it is getting automatically created when using type as  "Loadbalancer" in service deployment file.

Comment: ELB is still perfectly good and does not cause this problem. The only thing I can think of with the information provided is response time of the services. I would be looking at logs to determine exact times requests arrive, durations of requests. I'd be hitting the services directly from an EC2 instance to check performance. I'd create an ALB by hand to see if it did anything differently. I'd be looking at VPC flow logs to see what's happening at a network level (this one is quite time consuming so do it last). If you would like more help after that you need to provide much more information.